# validate captcha when form submit using ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax, validation, captcha

how can i validate if the user has enter the right captcha using ajax? and prevent the form submission if `$_POST['captchainput'] != $_SESSION['code']`.

this is the markup

`<form action="captchaccept.php" method="POST" name="maincontact">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter the code" autocomplete="off" id="captchainput" name="captchainput">
   <img src="captcha.php" id="captchaimage">
</form>`

captcha.php

`

```
session_start();

$image_width = 135;
$image_height = 30;
$characters_on_image = 8;
$font = 'captchafont/acmesa.ttf'; 

$possible_letters = '23456789abcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
$random_dots = 10;
$random_lines = 30;
$captcha_text_color="0x142864";
$captcha_noice_color = "0x142864"; 

$code = ''; 

$i = 0;
while ($i < $characters_on_image) { 
    $code .= substr($possible_letters, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible_letters)-1), 1);
    $i++;
}

$_SESSION['code'] = $code;

$font_size = 14; 
$image = @imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);

$background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

$arr_text_color = hexrgb($captcha_text_color); 
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_text_color['red'], 
$arr_text_color['green'], $arr_text_color['blue']);

$arr_noice_color = hexrgb($captcha_noice_color); 
$image_noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_noice_color['red'], 
$arr_noice_color['green'], $arr_noice_color['blue']);

for( $i=0; $i<$random_dots; $i++ ) {
    imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$image_width),
    mt_rand(0,$image_height), 2, 3, $image_noise_color);
}

$textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $_SESSION['code']); 
$x = ($image_width - $textbox[4])/2;
$y = ($image_height - $textbox[5])/2;
imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $font , $_SESSION['code']);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);

function hexrgb ($hexstr) {
    $int = hexdec($hexstr);

    return array( "red" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x10),
    "green" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x8),
    "blue" => 0xFF & $int);
}`
```

captchaaccept.php

`
    session_start();

```
if(isset($_SESSION['code'])) {
    if(empty($_POST['captchainput']) === false) {
        if($_SESSION['code'] === $_POST['captchainput']) {
                        echo 'ok';
                    }
            }
    }`
```

can someone teach me how to use ajax validation for this captcha? or just show me an example , thanks in advance :)

Comment: what you posted here is working fine?

Comment: Here is a tutorial about AJAX,PHP, Captchas http://webcheatsheet.com/php/create_captcha_protection.php

Comment: yes its working fine but what i want is by using ajax it will automatically validate if the $_POST and $_SESSION is the same after the user submit the form and if it is not equal it will prevent the form to submit and display a error message

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! You can improve your question by explaining more of what you want: What do you mean by "validating with AJAX"? What does it mean "to prevent form submission" ? Further, I don't think the code for captcha.php is useful at all - you should remove that unless your problem has a specific relation to this code.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can do it like this:

```
(function($) {
    $('#captchainput').on('submit', function(e) {
        // Prevent the browser submitting the form
        e.preventDefault();

        // Put the form in variable form
        var form = $(this);

        // Do a AJAX post with the form data and check the response
        $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(data) {
            if(data === 'ok') {
                // Captcha passed!
            } else {
                // Captcha failed!
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Also in your code;
`<form action="captchaccept.php" ...` should be
`<form action="captchaaccept.php" ...`  I think ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one also...

```
var posted_captcha = $( "#captchainput" ).val();
$.ajax({
          url    : 'captchaaccept.php',
          data   : 'captchainput=' + posted_captcha,
          type   : 'post',
          success: function (res) {
            if(res=='ok'){
                alert('Validation pass');
            }else{
                alert('Validation fail');
            }
          }
        });
```